# Flow Sending Duplicate Emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, email

I have a flow that sends a copy of the Purchase Requisition form to the creator after they have submitted it. A couple of the fields are Person or Group fields that allow for multiple entries. The flow is sending the same email to the creator multiple times if the Person or Group fields contain more than one entry. There are two differences between the emails. One, is the order that the entries are in and the second is the link to access their entry for updates does not work on the email where the second entry is listed first in the form. How do I stop this from happening? I am attaching a screenshot of my flow in addition to the differences in the email.

Thank you

[image: Email Differences]
[image: Flow #1]
[image: Flow #2]